# uninstall sybase adaptive server enterprise suite

Tags: sybase

uninstallion of sybase adaptive server enterprise suite is hanged at 0% since a long time. Does anyone know location of uninstall logs so that I can identify what is blocking uninstallation process.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase does not uninstall for Control Panel but successfully uninstalls from Uninstall executable placed in Sybase Installed directory path.